# Codingbat array2 no14

Tags: java

I am doing problems in coding bat. About this problem, I think I have done correctly but the result is not right. Please help me to find out the mistakes.

Problem : Given an array of int, return true if it contains no 1's or it contains no 4's.

```
        no14({1, 2, 3}) → true
        no14({1, 2, 3, 4}) → false
        no14({2, 3, 4}) → true
```

the following are my codes:

```
   public boolean no14(int[] nums) {
   int i=0;
   int count1=0;
   int count4=0;
   while(i<nums.length)
   {
   if(nums[i]==1)
    {count1++;}
    i++;
   }
   while(i<nums.length)
   {
     if(nums[i]==4)
     {count4++;}
     i++;
   }
   if(count1==0&&count4!=0)
   {return true;}
   else if(count1!=0&&count4==0)
   {return true;}
   else if(count1==0&&count4==0)
   {return true;}
   else return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {
    boolean ones = false, fours = false;

    for(int i = 0; i &lt; nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] == 1) {
            ones = true;
        } else if(nums[i] == 4) {
            fours = true;
        }
    }
    return (!ones) || (!fours);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think many of the solutions here are flawed due to people not reading the problem description carefully enough.
Simply returning false if a 1 or a 4 is found is incorrect.

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums){

/*  Given an array of ints, return true if it contains no 1's OR it contains no 4's. 

    no14({1, 2, 3}) = true
    no14({1, 2, 3, 4}) = false
    no14({2, 3, 4}) = true
*/  

    boolean containsNoOnes=true, containsNoFours=true;  //We assume we don't have any 1's or 4's.
    for (int i : nums) {
        if(i==1) containsNoOnes = false;                //If we find a 1, then false.
        if(i==4) containsNoFours = false;               //If we find a 4, then false.

    }       
    return containsNoOnes || containsNoFours;           //If array did not contain any 1's return true. 
                                                        //Or if array did not contain any 4's, return true;                                                           

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first while loop, you have to make the value of `i` to `0` before the second `while`

```
 while(i<nums.length)
   {
   if(nums[i]==1)
    {count1++;}
    i++;
   }
    i = 0;
   while(i<nums.length)
   {
     if(nums[i]==4)
     {count4++;}
     i++;
   }
```

You can return false as soon as you find a 1 or 4 to make it efficient.

Comment: thanks a lot. you are right. i thought in for() loop. "i" disappear after the loop ends. seems not the same situation in while.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made it overly complicated, if I understand what you're being asked to do - this should work -

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {
    for (int i : nums) {
        if (i == 1 || i == 4) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: yeah，you answer is good. thanks a lot. I did it with||, it works.

Comment: this solution is nont correct, just consider the first example no14({1, 2, 3}) → true but this function, after seeing the first 1 in the array, will return false..

Comment: @Cadavere *return true if it contains no 1's or it contains no 4's.* If it contains a 1 then it does not contain no 1's.

Comment: return true if (it contains no 1's) OR (it contains no 4's). With the example array {1,2,3} the second predicate is true, as it contains no 4's, so the function should return true, but your solution is returning false. You can check your function here: http://codingbat.com/prob/p136648

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {
    int one = 0;
    int four = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] == 1) one++;
        if (nums[i] == 4) four++;
    }

    if (one > 0 && four > 0) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {
  boolean isOne = false;
  boolean isFour = false;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
    if(!isOne && nums[i] == 1 ) {
       isOne = true;
    } else if(!isFour && nums[i] == 4) {
      isFour = true;
    }
  }
  return !(isOne && isFour);
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Comment: isOne is the flag to check whether the value is one, isFour is the flag to check whether the value is four. if isOne is true, means the value contains 1, so we do not need to check the rest of elements again, the same works for Four, only one condition that !(isOne && isFour) returns true, that is: the array contains 1 and 4

Comment: only one condition that isOne && isFour returns true, that is: the array contains 1 and 4, so for this condition !(isOne && isFour) returns false

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for this:

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {
  int count1 = 0;//counting 1's
  int count4 = 0;//counting 4's
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i] == 1){
      count1++;
    }
    if(nums[i] == 4){
      count4++;
    }
  }
  if((count1 == 0 && count4 > 0) || (count4 == 0 && count1 > 0) || (count4 == 0 && count1 == 0) )//checking if it contains only 1's or 4's or no one
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: You can directly return `((count1==0 && count4>0) || (count4==0 && count1>0) || (count4==0 && count1==0) )` instead of checking and returning `true/false`. Just an improvement suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
 public boolean no14 (int[] nums) {
     boolean is1 = false;
     boolean is4 = false;
     for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums [i] == 1)
           is1 = true;
        if(nums[i] == 4)
           is4 = true;
     }
     return(!(is1 && is4));
}
```